# Misaligned cabinet doors

Tags: cabinets

I have multiple misaligned kitchen cabinet doors and I’m unsure of how to fix the problem.   They look ridiculous and we’re putting our house on the market.   Any suggestions would be so greatly appreciated!!
[image] 
[image]
[image] 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The only adjustment you get with those hinges is the up and down adjustment the slots give. If your issue is that they aren't closing fully, the hinges pull themselves closed so long as the spring and nylon slipper aren't too worn - they look good in the photos, and there isn't any interference between the door and frame. In this case, there definitely is some contact between the bump on the door side half of the hinge and the frame, and this may be what is limiting the movement. I haven't seen this style of hinges with that bump pressed into the frame, but you may be stuck with carving away the material of the frame where the bump visibly comes into contact.

Comment: I agree the bump is contacting the frame work, I would not expect it to be the entire problem, I am thinking one of the hinges may be sprung. Kids hanging on doors really wipes out hinges like this as another possibility.+

Comment: YES!! @JACK, what he says!!! Get new hinges do not start cutting on the cabinets!!! It may work, but you need to know where and how much so it does not look like butchery!!!! JACK, post that as an answer, I will vote for it That spot on the hinge is just a symptom of how the hinge was bent. New ones will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Get a few new hinges from your home store.They are dirt cheap and easy to install.

Comment: Well, until you find that screw alignment is off by half a hole, and then you're left with either filling and re-drilling or having crooked screws. I'd bend the existing hinges back into shape first.